# How to order one-to-one entity by Doctrine 2 ORM?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

How to order by DESC one-to-one entity by Doctrine 2 ORM?

```
namespace Answer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Answer {

...

/**
 * @var Content
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Answer\Content", mappedBy="answer")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"creationDate" = "DESC", "contentId" = "DESC"})
 */
protected $currentContent;

...

}
```

"OrderBy" annotation worked with one-to-many and many-to-many associations only.

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer in your question.
The ORDER BY is applicated to the currentContent but if you have just one association (so with a OneToOne) you have just one entity of currentContent to sort so the ORDER BY isn't effective.

Comment: I need fetch last content of answer entity. How to do it? I used protected $content with OneToMany and OrderBy annotations and Array collection: return $this->content->current(). But this code selected all content entities from database.